# Call a shiny module a dynamic number of times using a for loop

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I've created a shiny module that display as much textInputs as the length of another variable on a row.

If I call these module one after the other manually, it works just fine:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

scenarios <- c("Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 3", "Scenario 4")

scenarioInput <- function(id, nomScenario){
  ns <- NS(id)
  textInput(inputId = ns("scenario"), label=nomScenario)
}

box1 <- shinydashboard::box(width=NULL, status="primary", align="center",
            HTML("<h1><strong>Scénarios</strong></h1>"), 
            splitLayout(
              cellWidths = rep(paste0(100/length(scenarios), "%"), length(scenarios)),   
              cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 2%"),
              scenarioInput(id=1, nomScenario=scenarios[1]),
              scenarioInput(id=2, nomScenario=scenarios[2]),
              scenarioInput(id=3, nomScenario=scenarios[3]),
              scenarioInput(id=4, nomScenario=scenarios[4])
            )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12,
           box1,
    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  body
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) { })
```

However, if I try to call these modules through a for loop, no textInput boxes is displayed to my screen.

```
box1 <- shinydashboard::box(width=NULL, status="primary", align="center",
            HTML("<h1><strong>Scénarios</strong></h1>"), 
            splitLayout(
              cellWidths = rep(paste0(100/length(scenarios), "%"), length(scenarios)),   
              cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 2%"),
              for (i in 1:length(scenarios)){scenarioInput(id=i, nomScenario=scenarios[i])}
            )
)
```

Would anyone know a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your textInputs as arguments to `splitLayout`.
This can be done via `do.call`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

scenarios <- c("Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 3", "Scenario 4")

scenarioInput <- function(id, nomScenario) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  textInput(inputId = ns("scenario"), label = nomScenario)
}

box1 <- shinydashboard::box(
  width = NULL,
  status = "primary",
  align = "center",
  HTML("<h1><strong>Scénarios</strong></h1>"),
  do.call(
    what = splitLayout,
    args = c(
      lapply(seq_along(scenarios), function(i) {
        scenarioInput(id = i, nomScenario = scenarios[i])
      }),
      list(cellWidths = list("10%", "20%", "30%", "40%")), # list(cellWidths = rep(paste0(100 / length(scenarios), "%"), length(scenarios))),
      list(cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 2%"))
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(fluidRow(column(width = 12, box1)))


ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    body)

shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = function(input, output) {  }
)
```

[image: result]

Comment: It works fine thank you, however the additional arguments of splitLayout are not taken into account here, which can be illustrated by changing cellWidths to random percentages. It's not that important here, but do you know if there would be a way to take into account the options so as to add space between the inputs?

Comment: Works fine on my system. Try e.g. `cellWidths = "5%"`.

Comment: If I use the same argument for all elements, for example `cellWidths = "5%"` it works, but if I try to have a different width for each box, e.g. `cellWidths = c("10%", "20%", "30%", "40%")` it doesn't work, while it worked in my non-dynamic code. 
The `cellArgs` argument also doesn't work, while it worked the first time. 
I assume that the issue is with the way additionnal arguments must be passed to the `do.call` function, but I have not been able to find a way to make it work.

Comment: Sorry - now I understand. The `args` list wasn't formatted properly (nested list). Please check my edit.